# Trouble with serving static files from pip installed package

Tags: python, pip, tornado

I'm having a package that wants to provide a visual "demo app". I added the HTML so that it is included in the package. I created a main function, and it is used as an entry point.

Whenever I run `sky view` from the main command from my local package, it is able to serve the `.css/.jss` files just fine, but whenever I serve them from:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/sky`

As from the entry point, it gives 404 errors for css and js (weirdly, not for the HTML files), like such:

```
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /static/css/app.css (::1) 0.55ms
```

What could be wrong?

In case people want to look at the code, it can be installed with `pip3 install sky`, or cloned from [github](https://github.com/kootenpv/sky/blob/master/sky/view/view.py).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `package_data` declaration in your `setup.py`. The CSS files aren't getting installed with the package, but the HTML files are (and JS should be; it's not clear to me what's wrong there).

Comment: Both when it is built, as well as it has been pip installed, the files are in the `templates/` folder, as well as in the `static/` folder. So I'm not sure what you refer to?

Comment: The folder I'm talking about is: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sky/view/static/js` (this is where the files are after installing the module).

Comment: https://github.com/kootenpv/sky/blob/a9c944a3c180d4a9cf59fb747b5602f5bec47bad/setup.py#L19 lists `*.js` but not `*.css`. So I would expect javascript files to work but not CSS. If the CSS files are getting installed then I don't know what's going on; this is probably more of a setuptools question than a Tornado question.

Comment: Sigh, this is indeed such a silly error! You were completely right. Completely useless question for the rest of SO.

Answer (score 0):

All the static files like .css and .js must be placed in a folder named static  to make them executable.Check if your are doing that.